# alias defined in .zshrc does not propagate to shell script

Tags: bash, zsh, alias

I have python installed on my system as `python3`. In my `.zshrc` file I defined following alias:

```
alias python=python3
```

With this, I am able to run `python3` using `python` on the command-line:

```
$ python
Python 3.11.6 (main, Nov  2 2023, 04:39:43) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But if I write a shell script `test.sh` like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
python
```

and then try to run this script as follows:

```
$ ./test.sh
```

I get:

```
./test.sh: line 2: python: command not found
```

What is going on here and how can I fix it? To be clear, this is on Mac but I think the result should be same on Linux. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to run `bash` in your script and have it use that alias then put the alias in your `.bashrc`, not your `.zshrc`, as `bash` and `zsh` are 2 completely different shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases and functions do not propagate to shell scripts. This is by design. They allow you to define nonstandard behavior for standard command names. Having those available in a script is likely to disrupt the script. This is especially true of aliases that are commonly used to add default options to commands.

If you have a script that expects a command that you have under a different name, create a symbolic link to that command in a directory that's in the `$PATH`. If the script needs a nonstandard version of a command, use a dedicated directory for running the script. For example, if you have a script that calls `python` explicitly, or a script with a `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang line, and you want it to invoke some different version of Python:

1. Create a directory e.g. `mkdir ~/myscript-bin`
2. Link the version you want in that directory, e.g. `ln -s /usr/bin/python4.2 ~/myscript-bin/python`
3. When running the script, put this directory first in the command search path: `PATH=~/myscript-bin:$PATH myscript`

For Python, there's quite a bit of tooling to help with having several versions around, and especially helps with managing libraries. If you have a script that requires a non-default version of Python or a non-default set of Python libraries, create a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for it.

```
python4.2 -m venv ~/myscript-env
# If the script needs extra packages:
(. ~/myscript-env/activate && pip install package1 package2)
(. ~/myscript-env/activate && myscript)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ed explained, zsh and bash are 2 different environments.  Since Apple changed its default shell to zsh and I still write my shell scripts in bash, I ended up placing my aliases in a .alias file then have both .zshrc and .bashrc source that.  I did the same for my functions.